# Change the height of a function being plotted

Tags: plotting, graphics, options, faq

How do I alter the height of any function plot using the `Plot` function?

Mathematica seems to limit the height of the plot up to the range of a function and distort the ratio of the Plot

[image]

Here in the above example the plot has a distorted axes ratio. How do I correct it?

Comment: Have you looked at `AspectRatio` in the options for `Plot`?

Comment: That doesnt alter the range display it just alters the relative height and width of the whole plot not only the YAxis

Comment: Oh, in that case, have you looked at `PlotRange`?

Comment: Tried that it does what I was looking for .But it increased the height of the plot graphic . Doesn't matter I can always use `AspectRatio` .I got this Finally -> [Plot](http://puu.sh/tcnk)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe `AspectRatio -> Automatic` which gives a 1:1 scaling of your function?

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -12, 12}, AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

If you take issue with the tight spaced tick-marks you can control that with [`Ticks`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/Ticks.html):

```
Plot[Sin[x], {x, -12, 12}, AspectRatio -> Automatic, Ticks -> {Automatic, {-1, 1}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]