# Finding normals to a curve through a given point

Tags: plotting, calculus-and-analysis, mathematical-optimization

I want to find x on curve $y(x)$, where curve $y(x)$ is perpendicular to point $(x_0,y_0)$.
for this I minimize the distance between points $(x,y(x))$ and $(x_0,y_0)$, here's an example for point $x_0=4,y_0=3$.

```
y[x_] := 2 + 0.36 x
NMinimize[(4 - x)^2 + (3 - y[x])^2, x]
```

But somehow this does not give the right answer though *Mathematica* seems to be finding the right minimum.

```
{0.171388, {x -> 3.85977}}
```

[image]

**Update:**

In a more practical case, with `Ei` some data to be fitted, and `sol2` the fitted coefficients of `U[...]` (refer to the end of the question for detail), this is what I tried:

```
Do[
 int = FindMinimum[{(Ei[1][[1, 2]] - U[x, 1] /. sol2[[2]])^2 + (i - x)^2}, x];
 AppendTo[perpendicular, int], 
 {i, 1, 30}]

cc = 
  ListPlot[{
    Evaluate @ Table[{i, Ei[1][[i, 2]]}, {i, 15, 23}], 
    Evaluate @
      Table[{x, U[x, 1] /. sol2[[2]]} /. perpendicular[[i, 2]], {i, 15, 23}]}, 
    Filling -> {1 -> {2}}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 5}, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic];

qq = 
  Plot[U[x, 1] /. sol2[[2]], {x, 15, 23}, 
    PlotRange -> {0, 5}, 
    AspectRatio -> Automatic];
```

[image]

This is the fitting function:

```
U[r_, o_] := 
  Sum[-ehh (1 - (1 - Exp[-Ahh (raa[i, j, o] - rshh)])^2), {i, 2, 
      5}, {j, 7, 10}] + 
    Sum[-ech (1 - (1 - Exp[-Ach (raa[i, j, o] - rsch)])^2), {i, 1, 
      1}, {j, 7, 10}] + 
    Sum[-ech (1 - (1 - Exp[-Ach (raa[i, j, o] - rsch)])^2), {i, 2, 
      5}, {j, 6, 6}] - 
    ecc (1 - (1 - Exp[-Acc (raa[1, 6, o] - rscc)])^2) /. x -> r;
```

And this the the fitted coefficients:

```
sol2 = {ehh -> -4.07603, Ahh -> 3.75309, rshh -> 1.44794, ech -> 0.223024, 
        Ach -> 1.51935, rsch -> 2.84276, ecc -> -4.52077, Acc -> 2.99396, 
        rscc -> 2.60361}
```

Comment: If your "curve" is a line, then you don't need optimization machinery; there's a nice geometric method for that purpose...

Comment: no it's not a line I just made this simple code for testing.

Comment: I'm not following you. It looks to me *the* right answer indeed. Or do you mean the plot looks not perpendicular? Have you tried `Plot` with option `AspectRatio -> Automatic`?

Comment: yes the plot doesn't look perpendicular to me if you know how you can plot it better please let me know too

Comment: Have you tried the option I mentioned above? Does it look right with that option?

Comment: I voted to close as I think your real question is merely about plot with specific aspect ratio, which in my opinion is a please-read-the-documentation question and too localized (also [might be duplicate](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/5223/17)).

Comment: actually no it's not silvia. it's about finding actual perpendicular line I don't really care about aspect ratio. as I mentioned in the title.

Comment: What @Silvia is saying is that the line through that point (probably) is perpendicular, and simply does not look so. This happens because aspect ratio !=1 will distort scale.

Comment: I think you *already* found the *actual perpendicular line*. You just *thought* you haven't because a plot with aspect ratio $\neq 1$ misled you.. If you try `Plot[y[x],{x,0,5},Prolog->{PointSize[.02],Through[{Point,Line}[{{4,3},{x,y[x]}/.x->3.85977}]]},AspectRatio->Automatic]`, you'll see what I mean.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I get even steps on x and y axes in a plot?](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/24990/how-can-i-get-even-steps-on-x-and-y-axes-in-a-plot)

Comment: What is `Ei` and `sol2`?

Comment: sol2 are the coefficients fired to the equation U[r,o], Ei is dataset fited to equation U[r,o] before, so the dots outside of line are Ei.

Comment: @RaymondGhaffarianShirazi I've edited the question according to your comment and voted for reopen. Please don't be hesitate to correct any possible mistake in case I misunderstood you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make a line from blue and red points on the curve you will see they all are kinda pointing at one point.

There I found a mistake at your code, I think Ei[1][[1 , 2]] this is a static number, I guess it should be a various number changing by iterator i so you're finding minimum b=distance between 2 different points each time.

```
Do[
 int = FindMinimum[{(Ei[1][[i, 2]] - U[x, 1] /. sol2[[2]])^2 + (i - x)^2}, x];
 AppendTo[perpendicular, int], 
 {i, 1, 30}]
```

Answer (score 4):

```
p = {x, y[x]} /. Last@NMinimize[(4 - x)^2 + (3 - y[x])^2, x]
(* {3.85977, 3.38952} *)

Dot[({4, 3} - p ), ({0, y[0]} - {5, y[5]})]

(* -3.9641*10^-8 *)
```

Numerically zero. As others said it doesnt look right on your plot because of the aspect ratio of the plot, try this:

```
Show[{ Plot[ y[x] , {x, 0, 5} ] ,  Graphics[Line[ {{4, 3}, p}]]}, 
       AspectRatio -> Automatic]
```

[image]

Comment: Of course, since the base curve whose normal you're seeking is a line, you can do this: `-(x - 4)/0.36 + 3`.

Comment: I used you command   AspectRatio -> Automatic but still in the curve i was working on actually it seems not perpendicular

Comment: Why not check mathematically if they are perpendicular, rather than by eye? Evaluate the slopes m1 and m2 at the intersection point and check that m1 == -1/m2